# Prepared SQLite statement with named parameter that contains spaces

Tags: sqlite

In SQLite you can use named parameters in statements, like this (Python example):

```py
cur.execute("insert into lang values (:foo, :bar)", {'foo': 'a', 'bar': 2})
```

Is there any way to have parameter names containing spaces? I.e:

```py
cur.execute("insert into lang values (:'foo bar')", {'foo bar': 'a'})
```

[The documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) suggests not but you never know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently for the `@AAA` form [you can](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam):

> The identifier name in this case can include one or more occurrences of "::" and a suffix enclosed in "(...)" containing any text at all.

But that doesn't let you have an *arbitrary* name since the brackets are still part of the name. So the answer appears to be no.